# Accumulator returns NaN in reduce function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I am learning to use `...`, the spread operator, to write a function that takes all the parameters passed to a function and returns the sum of the even ones.   My question is that why my acc equal to NaN except the first callback of reduce()?

The code and the executed print-out are below, and `console.log(...)` are the debugging code I inserted.  Thank you for your help.

```js
function sumEvenArgs(...args){
      var sum = args.reduce( (acc, next) => {
        console.log("\nnext:", next);
        if (next % 2 === 0) {
          acc += next;
          console.log("in if - acc:", acc);
        } else {
          acc += 0;
          console.log("in else - acc:", acc);
        }
      }, 0);

      return sum;
    }
    var sum = sumEven(1,2,3,4) // 6
    console.log("sum:", sum);
```

**Output**:

```
next: 1
in else - acc: 0

next: 2
in if - acc: NaN

next: 3
in else - acc: NaN

next: 4
in if - acc: NaN
sum: undefined
```

Comment: You're not returning `acc` at the end of each loop.

Answer (score 1):

you should return **acc** at the end of your callback function

```js
function sumEvenArgs(...args){
    var sum = args.reduce( (acc, next) => {
        console.log("\nnext:", next);
        if (next % 2 === 0) {
            acc += next;
            console.log("in if - acc:", acc);
        } else {
            acc += 0;
            console.log("in else - acc:", acc);
        }
        return acc ; // you need to add this line 
    }, 0);

    return sum;
}
var sum = sumEvenArgs(1,2,3,4) // 6
console.log("sum:", sum);
```